# Подключение словаря синонимов postgres

Tags: postgresql

Интересует такой момент, словарь синонимов и стоп-слов для полнотекстового поиска Postgres имеет форму текстового файла, а можно ли заставить СУБД работать не с файлом, а таблицей? То есть синонимы это таблица из двух колонок, например, регулярно пополняется.

Comment: Вам, наверное, легче будет сделать, например, cron-задачу, которая раз в N секунд обновляет словари и вызывает обновление внутри сервера.